# Firestore do not create

Tags: python, firebase, if-statement, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a Python code connected to `Cloud Firestore`. I want my code to skip and not create a document if the document's id is 1

```
if docid == 1:
    # do not create document

else:
   db.collection(u'collection_of_work').document(docid).set(data)
```

How to "not create" a document?

Comment: I see there are couple of potential answers but can you clarify what you're asking as the question is a bit vague. Looking at your code, if docid equals 1 then the code within that will execute, which we assume, does not create a document. The code in the else statement will never execute when docid is 1. So.... what's the issue?

Comment: can you please give your feedback on the below answers or elaborate further on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use an if statement for that (I assume you know the `docid` since you want to set the doc using that `docid`):

```
if docid != 1:
    db.collection(u'collection_of_work').document(docid).set(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can do that automatically. You have to check that. So you need to create a reference that points to the document with a particular ID and read it. If it already exists, then simply increment the number by one and create another set() operation.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [firebase-admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#python)

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate(
        "firestore-cred.json"
    )

firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()  

query_docid = db.collection(u'collection_of_work').document(u"1", u"==", docid).get()
    
if query_docid:
    print('do not create docuement')
else :
    db.collection(u'collection_of_work').document(docid).set(data)
```

My problem also was similar to this. I learnt the answer by [Barış Şenyerli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12686246/bar%C4%B1%C5%9F-%C5%9Eenyerli)

If you can't find the answer [this guy](http://%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#python)  will help you.

*All the best*